# role of service element in web.config file for a WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, config

what's the exact role of service element in web.config file for a WCF? I have seen instances where WCF services work perfectly without service element.

Here's a sample config file, whose service I can call from code behind & script (same/different  domain)

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
 </system.web>

 <system.serviceModel>    

<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>

<!--Calling from different domain -->
  <standardEndpoints>
  <webScriptEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name="" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
  </standardEndpoint>
  </webScriptEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="EndPointBehavior">
      <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>   

 </system.serviceModel>

 <system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
 <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
 </system.webServer>

 </configuration>
```

Comment: Do you want me to post the config file only or entire application where I can demonstrate the said scenario? Just editing my question to add config file, lemme know if it's not enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginning with WCF 4.0, the framework introduced the concepts of default endpoints, behaviors and bindings.   This was to make WCF configuration easier.  In the config file you posted, there are no defined endpoints or bindings, so the service will create a default endpoint at the location of the service file (i.e., if you have the service file at `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyService\MyService.svc` and the IIS Application is named `MyService`, it would be `http://<servername>\MyService\MyService.svc`).

The out of the box default binding is `basicHttpBinding` for `http`.  So this gives you a default endpoint with `basicHttpBinding`.  You can still explicitly define endpoints and bindings, and you can define a binding and set it to be the default for all services in that config that use that binding (by omitting the `name` attribute), and you can also change the binding used for a given transport in `<protocolMapping>` section in the `<system.serviceModel>` section.  For example, if you wanted to use `wsHttpBinding` for all `http` requests by default, you could do this:

```
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
</protocolMapping>
```

There's a very good article that covers this here - [A Developer's Introduction to Windows Communication Foundation 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx).